# clean imported xls file with php

Tags: php, xls

When I import XLS files, I would like to avoid the import of empty rows. I tried with several codes without success. Can anyone help me?

This is the code:

```php
require('xls/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require('xls/SpreadsheetReader.php');
require_once '_inc/_db.php';

$r = rand();
$mimes = ['application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/xls', 'text/xlsx', 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'];

if (in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $mimes)) {
    $uploadFilePath = 'storage/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFilePath);
    rename($uploadFilePath, "storage/" . $r . ".xls");
    
    $uploadFilePath = "storage/" . $r . ".xls";
    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($uploadFilePath);

    $totalSheet = count($Reader->sheets());

    $tot = 0;
    /* For Loop for all sheets */
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalSheet; $i++) {
        $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
        $tots = $totalSheet;
        foreach ($Reader as $Row) {
            $tot++;
            $nrcontenitore = isset($Row[0]) ? $Row[0] : '';
            $nrcontenitore = str_replace(".", "", $nrcontenitore);
            $nrcontenitore = str_replace("-", "", $nrcontenitore);
            $nrcontenitore = str_replace("_", "", $nrcontenitore);
            $nrcontenitore = str_replace("/", "", $nrcontenitore);
            $nrcontenitore = str_replace("\'", "", $nrcontenitore);
            $nrcontenitore = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $nrcontenitore);

            $nrcontenitore = isset($Row[0]) ? $Row[0] : '';
            $data = isset($Row[1]) ? $Row[1] : '';

            $doc .= formatcontainernr(strtoupper($nrcontenitore)) . " | " . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data)) . "\n";
            $docarr .= formatcontainernr(strtoupper($nrcontenitore)) . " | " . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data)) . "#\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to import a XLS file with no empty rows.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `continue` statement if the $row array is empty?

Answer (score 1):

try to add a checking if the row is empty

```
foreach ($reader as $row) {
  if($row == null){
    continue;
   }
}
```